# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.?

Tags: python, django

I created an app called djecommerce. Got an error in urls.py saying ImproperlyConfigured here's the code

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In the 6th line it showing the error near path

In the wsgi.py it showing error of no module found 'djecommerce' near application word. Here's the code

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djecommerce.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Kindly add the full error message to your question. And the `wsgi.py` is not necessary if you did not change it.

Comment: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested settings, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings. This is the error I am getting in the urls.py of my djecommerce app

Comment: Try adding this `settings.configure()` before the `settings.DEBUG` condition in your `urls.py`. The data you provided is not enough for me to propose any other solutions.